# Angular 2 : EXCEPTION: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm trying to implement a REST API into my angular 2 code but i have problem with getting the data from express by angular

When i remove the Angular component there is no error so most probably it's causing the problem. i also can access the data by server route `http://localhost:3001/task` so data is recived by express

This is my `server.js`

```
        'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const jwt = require('express-jwt');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

var tasks = require('./routes/tasks');

var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

app.use('/tasks', tasks);



// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());


const authCheck = jwt({
  secret: new Buffer('0u33qUTwmPD-MFf56yqJ2DeHuQncgEeR790T3Ke1TX3R5R5sylVfUNlHWyqQS4Al', 'base64'),
  audience: 'PBNaD26w0HdAinA5QFSyABjWZNrZSx9M'
});




const upload = multer({
  dest: 'uploads/',
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
      cb(null, `${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}${ext}`);
    }
  })
});

app.post('/upload', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.files.map(file => {
    let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    return {
      originalName: file.originalname,
      filename: file.filename
    }
  }));
});

app.get('/api/deals/public', (req, res)=>{
  let deals = [
  {
    id: 12231,
    name: 'Playstation 4 500GB Console',
    description: 'The Playstation 4 is the next gen console to own. With the best games and online experience.',
    originalPrice: 399.99,
    salePrice: 299.99
  },
  {
    id: 12234,
    name: 'Galaxy Note 7',
    description: 'The Note 7 has been fixed and will no longer explode. Get it an amazing price!',
    originalPrice: 899.99,
    salePrice: 499.99
  },
  {
    id: 12245,
    name: 'Macbook Pro 2016',
    description: 'The Macbook Pro is the de-facto standard for best in breed mobile computing.',
    originalPrice: 2199.99,
    salePrice: 1999.99
  },
  {
    id: 12267,
    name: 'Amazon Echo',
    description: 'Turn your home into a smart home with Amazon Echo. Just say the word and Echo will do it.',
    originalPrice: 179.99,
    salePrice: 129.99
  },
  {
    id: 12288,
    name: 'Nest Outdoor Camera',
    description: 'The Nest Outdoor camera records and keeps track of events outside your home 24/7.',
    originalPrice: 199.99,
    salePrice: 149.99
  },
  {
    id: 12290,
    name: 'GoPro 4',
    description: 'Record yourself in first person 24/7 with the GoPro 4. Show everyone how exciting your life is.',
    originalPrice: 299.99,
    salePrice: 199.99
  },
  ];
  res.json(deals);
})

app.get('/api/deals/private', authCheck, (req,res)=>{
  let deals = [
  {
    id: 14423,
    name: 'Tesla S',
    description: 'Ride in style and say goodbye to paying for gas. The Tesla S is the car of the future.',
    originalPrice: 90000.00,
    salePrice: 75000.00
  },
  {
    id: 14553,
    name: 'DJI Phantom 4',
    description: 'The Drone revolution is here. Take to the skies with the DJI Phantom 4.',
    originalPrice: 1299.99,
    salePrice: 749.99
  },
  {
    id: 15900,
    name: 'iPhone 7 - Jet Black',
    description: 'Get the latest and greatest iPhone in the limited edition jet black.',
    originalPrice: 899.99,
    salePrice: 799.99
  },
  {
    id: 16000,
    name: '70" Samsung 4K HDR TV',
    description: 'Watch as if you were there with the latest innovations including 4K and HDR.',
    originalPrice: 2999.99,
    salePrice: 2499.99
  },
  {
    id: 17423,
    name: 'Canon t8i DSLR',
    description: 'Capture life\'s moments with the amazing Canon t8i DSLR',
    originalPrice: 999.99,
    salePrice: 549.99
  },
  {
    id: 17423,
    name: 'Xbox One S',
    description: 'Get the latest Xbox and play the best first party games including Gears of War and Forza.',
    originalPrice: 299.99,
    salePrice: 279.99
  },
  ];
  res.json(deals);
})


app.listen(3001);
console.log('Listening on localhost:3001');
```

tasks.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://mojtaba:123456@ds129038.mlab.com:29038/mytasklist_mojtaba', ['tasks']);

// Get All Tasks
router.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next){
    db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(tasks);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Angular 2**

task.component.ts :

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import {TaskService} from './task.service';
    import {Task} from '../../Task';


    @Component({
      selector: 'tasks-component',
      templateUrl: 'tasks.component.html'
    })

    export class TasksComponent {
      tasks: Task[];
      title: string;

      constructor(private taskService:TaskService){
        this.taskService.getTasks()
          .subscribe(tasks => {
            this.tasks = tasks;
          });
      }

      addTask(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var newTask = {
          title: this.title,
          isDone: false
        }

        this.taskService.addTask(newTask)
          .subscribe(task => {
            this.tasks.push(task);
            this.title = '';
          });
      }
    }
}
```

task.service.ts :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class TaskService{


  constructor(private http:Http){
    console.log('Task Service Initialized...');
  }
  /*
   getTasks(){
   console.log('get tasks works');
   return this.http.get('/tasks')
   .map(res => res.json());
   }

   */
  getTasks(){
    return this.http.get('/tasks')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

**Errors** 
[image]

I tried to send JSON instead of html to client but it doesn't work. so what should i do?

Comment: Can you share your json data? I think the problem is in ur json data.

Answer (score 1):

This is error means your ajax call ( http.get ) is accessing a html page and then your trying to parse that into JSON.

in your express , you have a route for /task , but in your service , you're trying to access /api/task , which I think does not exist.

So you need to either change the express api , or change your http.get method .

So either :

```
app.get('/api/tasks', (req, res)=>{
    db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(tasks);
    });
});
```

OR :

```
getTasks(){
    console.log('get tasks works');
    return this.http.get('/tasks')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

In all cases , the best way to make sure that you're hitting the correct api is to look at your network tab and see the url that you're hitting with your AJAX call , then copy paste it into your browser ( or better , postman ) to see what's the response,

In your case I think you'd see : Can't get route api/task , which is thrown by express server.

Answer (score 0):

Change `return this.http.get('/api/tasks'` to return `this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/tasks')`

Answer (score 0):

> you have not defined your route properly in express. You have defined
>   all endpoints as *"/tasks"* and *"/upload"*. However, you are trying
>   to access *"/api/tasks"*. Better way to use express **Route
>   class(express.Router)** or **app.route()** method to create distributed
>   route.

```
Basic Use:
//Using app.route()
app.route('/api/tasks')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Get a random task')
  })
  .post(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Add a task')
  })
  .put(function (req, res) {
    res.send('Update the task')
  })
//Using express.Router
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})
// define the about route
router.get('/about', function (req, res) {
  res.send('About birds')
})

module.exports = router
```

Check the documention here. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Check your body parser implemention.Since middleware works on pipe.It should be on top of your route. 
See example:
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

Comment: updated the code to use express.router but still get the same error. it because it send html instead of json (checked the network) but don't how to fix it. btw my solution works but want to use express.router

Comment: Ok, Check HTML data on network. Is it any error html, like route not found?

Comment: I got you, You are using body parser in wrong way. It is pipe. You should use body parser and other middle ware on top.

Comment: Example:
https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser
<br>


var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})

Comment: Updated my answer. please check :-)

Answer (score 0):

your `res.json()` does not have any data to parse so try to pass the `tasks` to it

```
   getTasks(){
    console.log('get tasks works');
    return this.http.get('/tasks')
      .map(res => res.json(tasks));}
```